# How to access component data outside export

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am fairly new to Vue, I was trying out before we start out our project and so far I have come across one problem.

Usually when we create an instance like "**var app = new Vue** ... e.t.c " we can access it is data like **app.data** but what about in components like this

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    Hello {{msg}}

  </div>
</template>

<script>   

export default {
  name: "App",  
  data() {
    return { 
        msg: "World"
    }  
}

}

console.log(this.msg)

</script>
```

I just want to access the **msg** but so far I have been unable to, have tried also **this.msg** maybe I am missing something. I don't want to use Vuex at the moment i think it is overkill for a small app which isn't that complex.

So how do I access it?

Comment: You can, but I will not suggest it. This is an example of an [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) and it would behoove you to re-think your architecture here.

Comment: Ohgodwhy what can be the solution ? vuex? event bus?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with "access the msg" what are you trying to archieve,

Comment: Bob Fanger trying to output msg value which is "World" but I get this error Cannot read property 'msg' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about if Vue has any limitations but from javascript point can't you just do

```
 const data = {
   name: "App",  
   data() {
       return { 
         msg: "World"
      }  
   }

}

export default data;

const msg = app.data();
```

Comment: In Vue the data() is called for every new component to initialize it's internal state. This sollution shows what the data is for new components, but it doesn't access the msg of a specific component instance.